# jquery mobile: field contain clipped

Tags: html, iphone, jquery-mobile

```
<form>
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>Username:</legend>
        <input type="text" name="username">
    </fieldset>
</div>
</form>
```

If I set a form width

```
form {
width: 300px;
}
```

On Iphone 4s, in portrait mode, the username label is shown on the same line as the username input, and the username label is clipped. If there is not enough width for both username label and input, the label should be displayed above the input. Why? If I remove the width:300px, it is responsive to width well.

In landscape mode, the username label is shown above the input (as expected).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The field contain uses media queries based on screen width to place the label. You can use some CSS to override the media query CSS when you fix the form size:

```
<form>
    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
    </div>
</form>

form {
    width: 300px;
}
form .ui-field-contain {
    padding-top: 0.8em;
    padding-bottom: 0.8em;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
form .ui-field-contain label, form .ui-field-contain div {
    float: none !important;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.4em;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/gpf8g5ds/)**

Comment: Thanks. From the demo, the label is always above the input. I like to be responsive. For ipad with big screen, i like the label to be on the left of the input.

Comment: In my case, the input part is a div that contains many different inputs. So I use the fieldset with legend.

Comment: @Dave, setting form width to 300px stops it from being responsive, so which do you want?